# How to open a window in fullscreen with batch

Tags: batch-file

I made a batch file earlier with the code

```
    start chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" http://drive.google.com
```

It opens google chrome to the page "Drive.google.com" as the profile 1 user.
However, everytime i run it it opens chrome in a tiny window. I was wondering if there was a way to open it in either fullscreen mode or a larger windowed mode. I tried the

```
    mode con lines=1000 cols=1000
```

But it seems to be only for batch files. Is there a variable simlilar to the profile variable that will open it in fullscreen?

Comment: Just to clarify you don't want maximized, you want fullscreen only? Because with the flag "/max" after the "start" command you get the windows maximized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As waeswaes said you can add the `/max` tag

```
/MAX         Start window maximized.
```

So:

```
start /max chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" http://drive.google.com
```