# Batch file to open fullscreen website

Tags: batch-file

How do you open a website from startup, that'll run in fullscreen mode as well?
Using `/max` doesn't seem to do anything. That's for maximizing the screen. I want it to be like when F11 is pressed when you visit a website.
This is my file

```
@echo off

start chrome --profile-directory="Profile 1" "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

I've also looked into automatically having a key typed, but I can't get it to work. This is my first dabble with batch-file. Maybe it'll help you though:

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{F11}");
```

EDIT:
The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29725570/7024013) similar question isn't what helped me. As I've stated, `/max` is just to maximize the screen, whereas I want it to go fullscreen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a window in fullscreen with batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725570/how-to-open-a-window-in-fullscreen-with-batch)

Comment: It isn't. I have looked at that question and the given answer before I posted mine. The answer given there isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: `start -k www.microsoft.com` this is not F11 (full screen) but Kiosk mode. You can't unfull screen it.

Comment: `start iexplore -k www.microsoft.com`

Comment: Close enough alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send keys exactly to the window you want you have to focus on it first with [AppActivate](http://ss64.com/vb/appactivate.html) function.The [sendKeys.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat) do both with a single script

here's an example (at the moment I have no chrome driver so I'm using the standard chrome):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://stackoverflow.com/"
call sendKeys.bat "Stack" "{F11}"
```

the first argument is the title and the second the keys to be send.

According to this [list](http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/) `--start-fullscreen` argument should also work

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ways to do this.

`start "" "iexploerer.exe" -k "https://someurl.com"`

```
start "" "chrome.exe" -kiosk "https://someurl.com"
```

`start "" "firefox.exe" -kiosk "https://someurl.com"`